# What is the average case performance of this permutation-generating algorithm?

Tags: python, performance, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to determine the average case performance of this permutation-generating algorithm. It uses the recursive approach, in which the first element is swapped with each other element, producing a new set of permutations - these sets then go through the same routine, but with the first element fixed.

Here's the code in Python:

```
# Returns a list of all permutations of the given list.
def permutate(set):
    # A list of all found permutations, to be returned
    permutations = []

    # Takes a set which has all elements below index i fixed and finds all permutations
    def recurse(set, i):
        # If all elements are fixed, store the current permutation
        if i + 1 == len(set):
            permutations.append(set)
        else:
            # Swap the "first" element with each other element to generate new permutations
            for element in xrange(i, len(set)):
                set[element], set[i] = set[i], set[element]
                recurse(set, i + 1)
                set[element], set[i] = set[i], set[element]

    # Use the recursive algorithm to find all permutations, starting with no fixed elements
    recurse(set, 0)
    return permutations

print permutate([1, 2, 3])
```

I don't have much experience with analyzed recursive function performances, so I don't know how to solve this. If I had to make a guess, I would say that the runtime is *Θ(n!)*, because a set with *n* elements has *n!* permutations (so there must be that much effort put in by the algorithm, right?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `O(N!)` - the number of permutations. Proof follows trivially from the recursive formula which is about  `T(N) = N * T(N-1)` which is the formula of `N!`.

Comment: please add a python tag to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the complexity is `O(n!)` for the reason mentioned in the comment to the question.

But there are two other things.

1. Do not use `set` as a variable name, because you shadow a built-in data type
2. Your algorithm is not correct because of python implementation details

at the bottom of recursion, you append a resulting permutation to the `permutations` variable. But list in python is not passed by a value, so you actually append a reference to the input list. Because after `recurse` finishes its work, the input set is in the same order that it was at the beginning, so the `permutation` variable will store `n! references` to the same list. To fix that, you can use [deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) method of [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module, the resulting code is (notice that you can stop resursion when `i == len(s)`):

```
import copy

# Returns a list of all permutations of the given list.
def permutate(s):
    # A list of all found permutations, to be returned
    permutations = []

    # Takes a set which has all elements below index i fixed and finds all permutations
    def recurse(s, i):
        # If all elements are fixed, store the current permutation
        if i == len(s):
            # append a deepcopy of s
            permutations.append(copy.deepcopy(s))
        else:
            # Swap the "first" element with each other element to generate new permutations
            for element in xrange(i, len(s)):
                s[element], s[i] = s[i], s[element]
                recurse(s, i + 1)
                s[element], s[i] = s[i], s[element]

    # Use the recursive algorithm to find all permutations, starting with no fixed elements
    recurse(s, 0)
    return permutations

print permutate([1, 2, 3])
```